# NSMutableDictionary->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

The code below is running without any errors but is not giving me the exact result.

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        m_cAppIdMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        //enumerator = [m_cAppIdMap keyEnumerator];
    }
    return self;
}
-(BOOL)createTimer
{
    stRs232Timer*   pEvent = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));

    pEvent->bPersistent = YES;                              // setup timer structure
    //pEvent->pStack      = pStack;
    pEvent->wAppTimerId = 95;
    pEvent->uPeriod     = 50;
    pEvent->bStopped    = NO;
    wTimerId = 95;

    NSLog(@"bPersistent:%d",pEvent->bPersistent);
    NSLog(@"wAppTimerId:%d",pEvent->wAppTimerId);
    NSLog(@"uPeriod:%d",pEvent->uPeriod);
    NSLog(@"bStopped:%d",pEvent->bStopped);

    theLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    NSData* myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&pEvent length:sizeof(pEvent)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 96;
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 97;
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 98;
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 99;
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];


    NSLog(@"The dictionary count now is:%d",[m_cAppIdMap count]);
    NSLog(@"The dictionary values now is:");
    NSLog(@"%@",m_cAppIdMap);

    [self KillTimer:wTimerId];

    if ([theLock tryLock]) {
        //wTimerId=100;
        //[m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
        [theLock unlock];
    }   
    int k = [m_cAppIdMap count];
    NSLog(@"The count of dict :%d",k);
    NSLog(@"My dictionary is:%@",m_cAppIdMap);
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)KillTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerIds
{
    stRs232Timer* pEvent = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));
    BOOL bReturn=NO;
    theLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    if ([theLock tryLock]) {

        NSLog(@"Locked");
        NSEnumerator* enumerator = [m_cAppIdMap keyEnumerator];
        id key;
        while((key = [enumerator nextObject]))
        {
            NSLog(@"Into the while loop!!");
            if ([NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds] == key) {
             NSLog(@"Got key to remove");
             //[self findAndRemoveEvent:pEvent];
             [m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
              NSLog(@"Removed the key");
             free(pEvent);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"No key with this Id");
            }

            bReturn = YES;
        }
        NSLog(@"Unlocked!!");
        [theLock unlock];
    }   

    return bReturn;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
2011-05-24 19:19:02.915 NSArray[7558:a0f] bPersistent:1
2011-05-24 19:19:02.918 NSArray[7558:a0f] wAppTimerId:95
2011-05-24 19:19:02.919 NSArray[7558:a0f] uPeriod:50
2011-05-24 19:19:02.919 NSArray[7558:a0f] bStopped:0
2011-05-24 19:19:02.920 NSArray[7558:a0f] The dictionary count now is:5
2011-05-24 19:19:02.920 NSArray[7558:a0f] The dictionary values now is:
2011-05-24 19:19:02.921 NSArray[7558:a0f] {
    98 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    97 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    96 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    99 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    95 = <70c71000 01000000>;
}
2011-05-24 19:19:02.921 NSArray[7558:a0f] Locked
2011-05-24 19:19:02.925 NSArray[7558:a0f] Into the while loop!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.925 NSArray[7558:a0f] No key with this Id
2011-05-24 19:19:02.926 NSArray[7558:a0f] Into the while loop!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.926 NSArray[7558:a0f] No key with this Id
2011-05-24 19:19:02.927 NSArray[7558:a0f] Into the while loop!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.927 NSArray[7558:a0f] No key with this Id
2011-05-24 19:19:02.927 NSArray[7558:a0f] Into the while loop!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.928 NSArray[7558:a0f] No key with this Id
2011-05-24 19:19:02.928 NSArray[7558:a0f] Into the while loop!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.929 NSArray[7558:a0f] No key with this Id
2011-05-24 19:19:02.929 NSArray[7558:a0f] Unlocked!!
2011-05-24 19:19:02.930 NSArray[7558:a0f] The count of dict :5
2011-05-24 19:19:02.930 NSArray[7558:a0f] My dictionary is:{
    98 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    97 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    96 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    99 = <70c71000 01000000>;
    95 = <70c71000 01000000>;
}
```

In the code above i'm deleting the value corresponding to the key(wTimerId = 95).But 
Though the key is existing its not getting into the if loop and deleting the corresponding 
key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the same address here `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds] == key` rather than the same object. Try

```
...
if ( [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds] isEqual:key] ) {
...
```

Comment: @Deepak:Thanks.But i'm getting a runtime exception.2011-05-24 19:35:26.987 NSArray[7755:a0f] Locked
] Into the while loop!!
] No key with this Id
] Into the while loop!!
] No key with this Id
] Into the while loop!!
] No key with this Id
] Into the while loop!!
] Got key to remove
] Removed the key
] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <NSCFDictionary: 0x10010c730> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: That's because you're try to remove from an object you were fast enumerating. Can't you just say `[m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];` and remove the entire loop. This will remove the element if it exists.

Comment: @Deepak:Yeah i'm having the element and the element i'm going to delete is with the wtimerId 95.Then why is it throwing me an runtime exception.Its getting into the if loop and after deleting it its throwing me an exception.

Comment: @Deepak:Is it not possible to change the data while enumerating the values in the dictionary?

Comment: `Collection <NSCFDictionary: 0x10010c730> was mutated while being enumerated.` You can't delete an object from a dictionary while you're enumerating it.

Comment: @Deepak:Is there any other way to delete the value for a particular key.

Comment: Yeah do it directly. `[m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];` without the loop.

Comment: @Deepak:Great yaar.It worked.In what scenario do we need to use the fast enumeration with the dictionaries.

Comment: Reading the content I guess. :)

Comment: @Deepak:Thanks.You saved my day.From morning till evening i was with this simple code.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all of this:

```
    NSEnumerator* enumerator = [m_cAppIdMap keyEnumerator];
    id key;
    while((key = [enumerator nextObject]))
    {
        NSLog(@"Into the while loop!!");
        if ([NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds] == key) {
         NSLog(@"Got key to remove");
         //[self findAndRemoveEvent:pEvent];
         [m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
          NSLog(@"Removed the key");
         free(pEvent);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"No key with this Id");
        }

        bReturn = YES;
    }
```

with this:

```
[m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
```

The whole point of an `NSDictionary` is that you do not need to loop through the keys each time.

NB Deepak's answer as to why your if statement doesn't work is the correct one for that narrow question but he ignores the wider problem.

While you're at it, you should fix the memory leak.  You malloc pEvent but only free it if you find the key.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me where i'm mistaking..Is it possible to insert values into map during enumerations.Why do they use enumerations in Dictionaries.

Comment: You can't alter a collection in any way during an enumeration.  That includes inserts and deletes.  You enumerate dictionaries usually if there is something you want to do for every key/value pair in it e.g. if you want to print its contents or serialise it.